# Can't get data from firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to get the data from firestore for my user.
It is giving me blank in my textview.I dont know what this error is but I am also not able to pass data between activities and trust me I am doing everything right.I also added a toast to check the user id and it does show me the user id.The data just doesnt show up no matter what.I have used firestore the same way in my other project and it worked perfect there.I have also tried creating a new project but I am just not able to get the data from outside the activity.

**My logcat**

```
2020-06-02 11:15:52.749 19990-19990/? E/Zygote: v2
2020-06-02 11:15:52.750 19990-19990/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
2020-06-02 11:15:58.778 19990-19990/com.example.feedme2 E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

**My java class**

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView fullname;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    String user_id;
    String url;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profilepictureuser);
        Picasso.with(this).load(url).resize(400, 400).centerCrop().into(circleImageView);
        fullname = findViewById(R.id.profilename);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Toast.makeText(this, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("User data").document(user_id);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                fullname.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Full name"));
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation1);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.profilelogo);



        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.profilelogo:
                    return true;
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        });


    }
}
```

**My layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homepage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:id="@+id/profilepictureuser"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profilename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />



    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation1"
        android:background="#047cfb"
        app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My firestore rules**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**My firestore collection**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d98Y.png)

Comment: If you try to log the value of `getString("Full name")` inside the `onEvent`, is something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo no nothing is printed out in the logcat if I do that.

Comment: Is your `onEvent()` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo why do I need a onEvent listener.When I try to make a toast with the “Full name” it shows me blank.Please tell me if onEvent listener will make a difference as I am new to java and android studio.

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried doing that but it is giving null                                                                  2020-06-03 00:07:18.146 7886-7886/com.example.feedme E/Full name: onEvent: null

Comment: You can follow this [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java) doc in order to check how to get data from firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code to fetch the data on the main thread.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that as I am new to java and android studio.